# Slick Carousel Fixed inside arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

So today I have a problem and I have tried many things to try and fix it but nothing works I am currently using slick carousel for my carousel. The problem I have today is that I cant get the arrows to be fixed inside the carousel. I am trying to get the arrows to be fixed around the active item in the carousel.

Please if you can help me I would highly appreciate it! Thank You!

What I am trying to do : https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ2TQ.png

Code :

Jquery -

```
$('.carousel').slick({
   arrows: true,
   prevArrow: $(".serverArrow1"),
   nextArrow: $(".serverArrow2")
 });
```

Html -

```
<div class="quoteCarousel">
        <div class="quoteItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="quoteImage">
                    <img src="http://splory.my/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/round-profile-CH.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="quoteText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p class="quoteAuthor">John Doe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quoteItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="quoteImage">
                    <img src="http://splory.my/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/round-profile-CH.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="quoteText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p class="quoteAuthor">John Doe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quoteItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="quoteImage">
                    <img src="http://splory.my/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/round-profile-CH.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="quoteText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p class="quoteAuthor">John Doe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quoteItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="quoteImage">
                    <img src="http://splory.my/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/round-profile-CH.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="quoteText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p class="quoteAuthor">John Doe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="quoteItem">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="quoteImage">
                    <img src="http://splory.my/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/round-profile-CH.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <p class="quoteText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                <p class="quoteAuthor">John Doe</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="sliderButtons">
            <a href="#" class="serverArrow1">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="serverArrow2">
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
```

CSS -

```
.serverArrow1 {margin-right: 45%;}

.serverArrow2 {
margin-left: 45%;
}

.slick-arrow {margin-bottom: 10px;border: 1px solid #3b3b3b;padding: 10px 12px; border-radius: 50%;color: #060606;font-size: 2rem;}

.sliderButtons {position: absolute;bottom: 80px;right: 50px;left: 50px;}
```